# Laravel - Pusher - Detect when a user is no longer in the website or leaves the page

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm facing a problem with a real time app that i'm developing. My problem is about user's status using Pusher. I would like to get the correct way to detect when a user leaves the page or keep unactive for a while to set it's status to 'offline', for example. How could I achieve that? I'm almost sure that is not recommended develop this feature at client-side, it should be at server-side, but how? How can I ask to clients if they are still there? Should I create a command and run it wit cron? Are there any mechanism to let the server 'detect' the socket disconnection? Any help will be appreciated, Thx!

**Update**

With NoseJS and SocketIO it's really simple, you just have to write:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) { // When client connects
    socket.on('disconnect', function() { // Listen to disconnections from SERVER-SIDE
        // Logic when a user disconnects. This is what I want!
    });
});
```

But in Laravel, I only have this:

```
// A Laravel Event Class that implements the shouldBroadcast interface...
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        // I think here is where connections happen, but I don't know how to detect 'disconnections' :(
        return new PresenceChannel('someString');
    }
```

**PD**: I'm using Laravel Echo and Pusher :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [presence channels](https://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_presence_channels) to achieve this. You can then use [presence webhooks](https://pusher.com/docs/webhooks#presence) to notify your server whenever a user enters or leaves the channel.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'm currently using presence channels, however, I don't know where to listen to that events with Laravel. I can write a javascript code to notify server when users disconnect but it's possible that this client does not have enough time to make that request (user can close browser suddenly) so I'm looking for a Server-side implmentation, if possible.
I updated my question to show an implementation with NodeJS+ SockeIO, basically, it can listen to 'disconnect' event from server side. I want the same using Laravel <3

Comment: You need to enable [webhooks](https://pusher.com/docs/webhooks) and configure them to send to your Laravel server. Then you will need configure a Laravel route and controller to handle them. You are specifically looking for the `member_removed` webhooks.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to subscribe to the the `ConnectionClosed` event

`Providers/EventServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Events\ConnectionClosed;
use App\Listeners\OnConnectionClosed;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        ConnectionClosed::class => [
            OnConnectionClosed::class
        ]
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }
}
```

`Listeners/OnConnectionClosed.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\Events\ConnectionClosed;

class OnConnectionClosed
{
    public function handle(ConnectionClosed $connection)
    {
        if( !is_null($connection->appId) && !is_null($connection->socketId) ){
            error_log($connection->appId);
            error_log($connection->socketId);
        }
    }
}
```