# Laravel Echo Server - Detect user disconnection

Tags: laravel, websocket, webhooks, server-side, laravel-echo

Im currently using laravel echo for my realtime chat app using presence channel and facing the same problem with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46930028/5195660).

Different thing is that I'm using Laravel echo server instead of pusher for socket server.

However I'm looking for laravel echo server side implementation beside [pusher webhooks](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/webhooks#presence) to get notified of user disconnects.

Any possible solution?

Comment: Let's start with what you've tried. "I've done echo server" is simply not enough. You need to show the implementation. How have you done it? What is actually happening vs expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question. I found a [PR on laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/pull/378) which has hooks feature to listen to client-side events from server. Finally I'm now in peace.

Comment: How did you install it? I tried `sudo npm install -g  https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server/tarball/master` but it is returning error on running...